# How to convert font-size from points to view units

Tags: html, css

My site is designed entirely with CSS grid, and everything is responsive except the text.  My text is defined using points (e.g., 12pt).

I read that I should be using view units (vh for view height, vw for view width) instead of points or pixels.

I haven't found a formula to convert from points to vh and vw.  I'm trying to avoid using media queries.

Is there a formula to convert font-size from points to view units?  For example, what's 12 point in view units?

Comment: Do you need to convert points to view units given a certain screen size? Because if not, you won't be able to convert them in any standard way. A point is always the same size. View units will change size depending on the screen size

Comment: My understanding is that view units do not need to be specified per screen size because they respond based on the device.  So my question is what should I use for font-size:12pt in view units?

Comment: There isn't a way to convert from points to vw or vh. 100vh is the height of a viewport, and 100vw is the width of a viewport. A viewport unit is a different size depending on the size of the viewport, whereas 12pt is always the same.

Maybe you want to replicate something like this Fluid Typography post?
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/

Comment: That looks like a good solution, @missmatsuko.  Thanks for that suggestion.